# Making sure that kernel version is frozen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

I want to freeze my kernel version. I followed some instructions on a blog to hold the " linux-image-generic " package - however in my case I see a " linux-image-generic-lts-xenial ".

Basically

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

For me shows:

```
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-61-generic                         3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic                          4.4.0-38.57~14.04.1                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-61-generic                   3.19.0-61.69~14.04.1                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic                    4.4.0-38.57~14.04.1                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
hi  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial                        4.4.0.38.28                                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

I typed in the command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial linux-image-generic
```

Is this enough to freeze the kernel?

Rant: I am tired of Nvidia and my Wifi drivers breaking everything the kernel updates. Supposedly this version of the kernel needed MOK to "disable validation" to work, but even with validation - cuda seems to work fine. I just dont want to spend another work-day fixing my computer every time it bloody updates. Its frustrating.

Comment: Did you let Ubuntu initially download the driver on the 'additional drivers' tab? I did that last night and when I went back in all Nvidia and the Nouveau options were gone. That might have some bearing either way to this problem you and others are reporting.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No. I just let the auto-update do it's thing.